# Open [hidden] new window in webdriver without instantiating new driver in WebDriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium2

I've researched this to some extent already by searching StackOverflow and SQA, but cannot find the answer.

Is it possible to open a new WebDriver browser window from the current FirefoxDriver (IWebDriver) instance, or do I need to instantiate a new FirefoxDriver instance?  It would be nice to open a new tab, but I read that this is not possible with WebDriver.

The [hidden] part of my question .. bonus if you know, but not required.  :-)

And also, I don't even need to see this browser window, so I'd prefer that it's hidden.  Does the browser need to be seen or can I do the webdriver tests without having the task/browser open in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can interact with a window that is spawned as part of the automated test with this code:

```
void startSelenium() 
{
   driver_ = new FirefoxDriver();
   selenium_ = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver_,
  "https://....com");
}
 for (String handle : driver_.getWindowHandles())
{
      System.out.println("win " + handle);
      driver_.switchTo().window(handle);
      System.out.println("href: " + selenium_.getLocation());
}
```

I haven't tested this code, I got it from this page along with additional info: http://osdir.com/ml/selenium-users/2011-04/msg00440.html

For the second question about a hidden browser, I would suggest using the HTMLUnit driver. This would also solve any issues with simultaneous interaction with both windows.

Comment: I'll accept once I write the C# code for this and get it working